# Telegram Crypto Bot

Tags: python, api, telegram, coingecko

I have a problem. I'm getting Crypto information from CoinGeckoAPI. Information is not sorted. So I sorted. When I'm running this file with print. It works. But When I would like to reply user's message in Telegram, I have not got the same result. Problem relates to telegram's doc. I'm a new programmer, That's why I need Help.

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
from collections import OrderedDict
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR TOKEN')
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()


price = cg.get_price(ids=['bitcoin', 'ftx-token', 'cardano', 'the-graph', 'near', 'polkadot', 'avalanche-2', 'dogecoin', 'ethereum',
         'terra-luna', 'litecoin', 'matic-network', 'solana', 'binancecoin', 'uniswap'], vs_currencies='usd')
temp = price
temp = OrderedDict(sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['usd'], reverse=True))
print(temp)


bot.polling()
```

Result SORTED

```
OrderedDict([('bitcoin', {'usd': 37859}), ('ethereum', {'usd': 2572.28}), ('binancecoin', {'usd': 392.59}), ('litecoin', {'usd': 110.22}), ('solana', {'usd': 96.54}), ('avalanche-2', {'usd': 70.16}), ('terra-luna', {'usd': 52.13}), ('ftx-token', {'usd': 40.97}), ('polkadot', {'usd': 18.69}), ('near', {'usd': 11.25}), ('uniswap', {'usd': 11.07}), ('matic-network', {'usd': 1.72}), ('cardano', {'usd': 1.07}), ('the-graph', {'usd': 0.419375}), ('dogecoin', {'usd': 0.142963})])
```

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['main'])
def main(message):
    price = cg.get_price(ids=['bitcoin', 'ftx-token', 'cardano', 'the-graph', 'near', 'polkadot', 'avalanche-2', 'dogecoin', 'ethereum', 'terra-luna', 'litecoin', 'matic-network', 'solana', 'binancecoin', 'uniswap'], vs_currencies='usd')
    temp = price
    temp = OrderedDict(sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['usd'], reverse=True))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Crypto:\n'
                                      f'Bitcoin ~  {price["bitcoin"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Ethereum ~ {price["ethereum"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Near Protocol ~ {price["near"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'FTX Token ~ {price["ftx-token"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Litecoin ~ {price["litecoin"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Terra ~ {price["terra-luna"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Solana ~ {price["solana"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Polkadot ~ {price["polkadot"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Binance Coin ~ {price["binancecoin"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Dogecoin ~ {price["dogecoin"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Cardano ~ {price["cardano"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'The Graph ~ {price["the-graph"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Polygon ~ {price["matic-network"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Avalanche ~ {price["avalanche-2"]["usd"]} $\n'
                                      f'Uniswap ~ {price["uniswap"]["usd"]} $')

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, temp{temp})
```

Unsorted Result

```
Sabyr's crypto bot, [29.01.2022 19:24]
Crypto:
Bitcoin ~  37840 $
Ethereum ~ 2571.11 $
Near Protocol ~ 11.23 $
FTX Token ~ 40.98 $
Litecoin ~ 110.24 $
Terra ~ 52.21 $
Solana ~ 96.53 $
Polkadot ~ 18.71 $
Binance Coin ~ 392.64 $
Dogecoin ~ 0.143045 $
Cardano ~ 1.07 $
The Graph ~ 0.419587 $
Polygon ~ 1.72 $
Avalanche ~ 70.17 $
Uniswap ~ 11.08 $
```

Result DOESN'T MAKE SORTED

```
Sabyr's crypto bot, [29.01.2022 19:24]
bitcoin
```

Comment: Hi Sabyr, welcome to stackoverflow. I'm not clearly understanding the issue. It says "Result DOESN"T MAKE SORTED", what do you mean by that? What is result and what do you want to sort? Are you sorting by the $ amount or the name of the coin?

Comment: I wanted that my telegram bot send me this result. But instead of it. He sends me only bitcoin.

OrderedDict([('bitcoin', {'usd': 37859}), ('ethereum', {'usd': 2572.28}), ('binancecoin', {'usd': 392.59}), ('litecoin', {'usd': 110.22}), ('solana', {'usd': 96.54}), ('avalanche-2', {'usd': 70.16}), ('terra-luna', {'usd': 52.13}), ('ftx-token', {'usd': 40.97}), ('polkadot', {'usd': 18.69}), ('near', {'usd': 11.25}), ('uniswap', {'usd': 11.07}), ('matic-network', {'usd': 1.72}), ('cardano', {'usd': 1.07}), ('the-graph', {'usd': 0.419375}), ('dogecoin', {'usd': 0.142963})])

Comment: @lane 
I made a sorting method and writing result into txt file. So I have question. I can't send the including of this file.

Comment: def collect_data():
    s = requests.Session()
    response = s.get(url="https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cftx-token%2Ccardano%2Cthe-graph%2Cnear%2Cpolkadot%2Cavalanche-2%2Cdogecoin%2Cethereum%2Cterra-luna%2Clitecoin%2Cmatic-network%2Csolana%2Cbinancecoin%2Cuniswap&vs_currencies=usd")

    data = response.json()

    result_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['usd'], reverse=True)
    f = open('file2.txt', 'w')
    for i in result_data:
        line = ' '.join(str(x) for x in i)
        f.write(line + '\n')
    f.close()

Comment: import requests
import json
import telebot
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['pop'])
def bitcoin(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Please waiting...")

    collect_data()

Comment: @bot.message_handler(commands=['main'])
def pop(message):
    collect_data()
    myfile = open('file2.txt', 'r')
    for x in myfile:
        a_string = x
        alpha = ""
        numeric = ""
        for character in a_string:
            if character.isalpha():
                alpha += character
            if character.isdigit():
                numeric += character
            if character == ".":
                numeric += character
        new_list = alpha.upper()[0]+ alpha[1:-3]+" ~ "+" "+numeric + " $"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, new_list)

Comment: Glad you were able to sort it out! Sorry I was unable to respond in time. For the benefit of other users can you edit your question and add clarity? Also you can post the solution to your question in the answer section and select your own answer.